# Examples in which contractibility is not closure-preserved, not interior-preserved, not intersection-closed or not connected union-closed.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I read the following 4 theorems:
http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Contractible_space

(1) It is possible to have a topological space $X$ and a subset $A$ of $X$  such that $A$ is contractible in the subspace topology, but the closure $\bar{A}$ is not.

(2) It is possible to have a topological space $X$ and a subset  $A$ of $X$  such that $A$ is contractible in the subspace topology, but the interior of $A$ is not.

(3) It is possible to have a topological space $X$  and subsets $A$, $B$  of $X$ such that $A$, $B$ are both contractible in their respective subspace topology but $A\cap B$ is not.

(4) It is possible to have a topological space $X$  expressible as a union of subsets  $A$, $B$ , both contractible in their subspace topology, with  $A\cap B$ nonempty, but $X$ itself not contractible.

Can you give me concrete examples of this 4 theorems.

Comment: @fermesomme http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Contractible_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider $X = S^1$ and let $x\in X$, define $A = S^{1} - \{x\}$; $A$, under the subspace topology, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.
2. Consider $X = \mathbb R^2$, define $A$ to be two disjoint open discs that are connected by a line segment. The interior of $A$ will be the two open discs (without the segment.)
3. $X = S^1$, $x$ and $y$ be two distinct points in $X$. Define $A = X - \{x\}$ and $B = X - \{y\}$, and $A \cap B$ is homotopy equivalent to the discrete-subspace $\{x, y\}$.
4. Same example from 3 will work.